# nopCommerce admin log in in visual studio does not take me to admin area

Tags: nopcommerce

Hi I am trying to use nopCommerce for the first time. when I opened the solution in visual studio 2013 express I am having two  separate web applications :nop.admin and nop.web;
when i log in with admin credentials  this does not take me to admin area.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions in here:
http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/79/installing-nopcommerce.aspx

Running the site using Visual Studio (package with source code)
This step describes how to launch a site in Visual Studio. To run the site in Visual Studio, extract the full source code archive (.rar) to a local folder. Launch Visual Studio and select File > Open > Project/Solution. Navigate to the folder where you extracted the archive and open NopCommerce.sln solution file. Run Nop.Web project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild solution before starting.